# DAX/powerpivot equivalent to T-SQL where in

Tags: t-sql, powerpivot, dax

**I am unable to construct the query equivalent to the T-SQL below.**

I am working on our new analytics dashboard and I have solved almost everything what I wanted, but I have stuck on the one problem.

Image with table and T-SQL query
http://server.esterminal.cz/dax/all.PNG

**Table**

```
ID      ProductID   TimeID  StoreID Price

797190  7946        267     73      100

797191  7946        269     73      101

797192  7946        270     73      102

797193  7946        271     73      104

797194  7946        271     74      105

797195  7947        271     74      200

797196  7947        271     73      202

797197  7947        271     75      203
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ProductFact  
 WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID 
                       FROM ProductFact 
                      WHERE StoreID = 75)
```

**Result**

```
ID      ProductID   TimeID  StoreID Price

797195  7947        271     74      200

797196  7947        271     73      202

797197  7947        271     75      203
```

I want to show all the products that are on offer in one store and show the details of any other stores that stock the product.

I know that I have overlooked something "big", but after 6 hours of attempting to find a way, I decided to ask to someone who has more experience than me.

Thank you for help.

Michal

Comment: What are the results you would expect?  Based on your description, the query seems to be working.

Comment: The subject of this message is maybe incorrect. I would like to find DAX query with the same result as T-sql has.

Comment: I found solution which work for me.

EVALUATE

FILTER(

ProductFact,

CONTAINS(FILTER(ProductFact, ProductFact[StoreID]=75), 

ProductFact[ProductID], ProductFact[ProductID])

)

Comment: Put it in as an answer to your own question then mark it correct, not only will it help others see it more easily, but it will give you some reputation points - which you may be able to award as part of a bounty on a future to entice a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution which work for me.

EVALUATE FILTER( ProductFact, CONTAINS(FILTER(ProductFact, ProductFact[StoreID]=75), 
ProductFact[ProductID], ProductFact[ProductID]) )